# Simplify $(x+y+z)^{-1}(x^{-1}+y^{-1}+z^{-1})(xy+xz+yz)^{-1}\lfloor (xy)^{-1}+(xz)^{-1}+(yz)^{-1}\rfloor$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Given $\{x,y,z\} \subset \Bbb R^+$ express the following expression in simpler terms:
>   $$(x+y+z)^{-1}(x^{-1}+y^{-1}+z^{-1})(xy+xz+yz)^{-1}\left\lfloor (xy)^{-1}+(xz)^{-1}+(yz)^{-1}\right\rfloor$$

This question appeared in the "Olimpiada Campinense 2000" level 2 exam (Brazil). No answer provided.

My problem is how to deal with the floor terms.

**My attempt**: developing the original expression leads, I believe, to:
$$\frac{1}{(x+y+z)}\frac{1}{xyz}\left\lfloor \frac{x+y+z}{xyz}\right\rfloor$$

**Question:** how do I deal with the floor expression at this point, considering the development is OK? Please help.

Comment: it reduces to $\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{x+y+z}{x y z}\right\rfloor }{x y z (x+y+z)}$ but, how you want to simplify the floor function here ?!

Comment: @Ahmad is there any way of getting rid of the floor term in the expression? I'm not familiar the floor properties.

Comment: Without extra information you cant, for instance you need that $x y z >3$ or something like that, for instance when the numbers are big $x=2,y=3,z=4$ the floor function is $0$ but when they are small $x=0.01,y=0.02,z=0.031$ the floor function is $9838$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try. $$\frac{1}{x+y+z}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)\frac{1}{xy+yz+zx}\left(\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}\right) =\frac{1}{x+y+z}\frac{xy+yz+zx}{xyz}\frac{1}{xy+yz+zx}\frac{xyz(x+y+z)}{(xyz)^2} = \frac{1}{(xyz)^2}.$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the "floor" term in the expression? You just acted as if it was a parenthesis, but it is not.